# Vectorizing python code to numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code snippet (for Hough circle transform):

```
for r in range(1, 11):
    for t in range(0, 360):
        trad = np.deg2rad(t)

        b = x - r * np.cos(trad)
        a = y - r * np.sin(trad)

        b = np.floor(b).astype('int')
        a = np.floor(a).astype('int')

        A[a, b, r-1] += 1
```

Where `A` is a 3D array of shape `(height, width, 10)`, and
`height` and `width` represent the size of a given image.
My goal is to convert the snippet exclusively to numpy code.

My attempt is this:

```
arr_r = np.arange(1, 11)
arr_t = np.deg2rad(np.arange(0, 360))

arr_cos_t = np.cos(arr_t)
arr_sin_t = np.sin(arr_t)

arr_rcos = arr_r[..., np.newaxis] * arr_cos_t[np.newaxis, ...]
arr_rsin = arr_r[..., np.newaxis] * arr_sin_t[np.newaxis, ...]

arr_a = (y - arr_rsin).flatten().astype('int')
arr_b = (x - arr_rcos).flatten().astype('int')
```

Where `x` and `y` are two scalar values.

I am having trouble at converting the increment part: `A[a,b,r] += 1`. I thought of this: `A[a,b,r]` counts the number of occurrences of the pair `(a,b,r)`, so a clue was to use a Cartesian product (but the arrays are too large).

Any tips or tricks I can use?

Thank you very much!

Edit: after filling `A`, I need `(a,b,r)` as `argmax(A)`. The tuple `(a,b,r)` identifies a circle and its value in `A` represents the confidence value. So I want that tuple with the highest value in `A`. This is part of the voting algorithm from Hough circle transform: [find circle parameter with unknown radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform#Find_circle_parameter_with_unknown_radius).

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a dimension for `r` in `A`? It seems redundant.

Comment: @PaulPanzer - after filling `A`, I need `(a,b,r)` as `argmax(A)`. The tuple `(a,b,r)` identifies a circle and its value in `A` represents the _confidence value_. So I want that tuple with the highest value in `A`.

Comment: @Alex Maybe add that important info into the question.

Comment: Added this clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method #1**

Here's one way leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get the counts and update `A` (this assumes the `a` and `b` values computed in the intermediate steps are positive ones) -

```
d0,d1,d2 = A.shape    
arr_r = np.arange(1, 11)
arr_t = np.deg2rad(np.arange(0, 360))

arr_b = np.floor(x - arr_r[:,None] * np.cos(arr_t)).astype('int')
arr_a = np.floor(y - arr_r[:,None] * np.sin(arr_t)).astype('int')

idx = (arr_a*d1*d2) + (arr_b * d2) + (arr_r-1)[:,None]

A.flat[:idx.max()+1] += np.bincount(idx.ravel())
# OR A.flat += np.bincount(idx.ravel(), minlength=A.size)
```

**Method #2**

Alternatively, we could avoid `bincount` to replace the last step in `approach #1`, like so -

```
idx.ravel().sort()
idx.shape = (-1)
grp_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([True], idx[1:]!=idx[:-1],[True])))
A.flat[idx[grp_idx[:-1]]] += np.diff(grp_idx)
```

**Improvement with `numexpr`**

We could also leverage [`numexpr` module](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#how-it-works) for faster sine, cosine computations, like so -

```
import numexpr as ne

arr_r2D = arr_r[:,None]
arr_b = ne.evaluate('floor(x - arr_r2D * cos(arr_t))').astype(int)
arr_a = ne.evaluate('floor(y - arr_r2D * sin(arr_t))').astype(int)
```

Comment: I have to mention that those two `for` loops are nested under another two for loops (`for x` and `for y`). I have to compute this for every `(x,y)`.

Comment: @Alex But the question states - `Where x and y are two scalar values.`?

Comment: They are scalars (indices). This numpy code will be run for each `(x,y)`.

Comment: @Alex Yeah that should be okay. So, the proposed solution would plug inside the nested loops for `x` and `y`.

Comment: By accumulating `np.bincount(idx.ravel())`, right? And at the end of the loops for `x` and `y`, get the `argmax()`.

Comment: @Alex Cleaned up code. You might want to try out `method#2` as well. And `numexpr` is worth a go as well I think.

Comment: `Method #2` is faster. Also, can you elaborate on the logic behind it, please?

Comment: @Alex Well `idx` is array of flattened indices to be incremented in `A` and they appear as many times, the incrementing is to be done. So, we flatten `idx`, sort it. Then, get the start of each group of idenntical indices, that's `grp_idx`. Then, get count of each group of identical indices with `np.diff`. Finally, we use start of each group to select that flattened index corresponding to each group, index into flattened A and assign the counts.

Answer (score 2):

np.add(np.array ([arr_a, arr_b, 10]), 1)

Comment: What exactly are you doing here? I am seeing typos all over and still can't see how simply indexing with those indexing arrays would work out.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Corrected it. I understood Alex wants to increment the three values in his array using numpy which the above line does. He also wrote r is always 10 so I hard-coded the value.

Comment: And how are you updating `A`?